# Extract value from scraped webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

First attempt at using python and after a day of google my old brain is even more stumped.

I have used pycurl to log thru ntlm proxy and scrape page and then used beautifulsoup to prettify the result.

I want to extract 3 values from the prettify output and store them as variables. The page is dynamically generated so their location on page keeps changing. The 3 Labels only appear once on the page and their location compared to their respective values is constant.

How do I extract Value1, Value2 and Value3 from the prettify output and store them as variables.

These 3 oneliners are what i need to do in python.

grep -A 3 "Label1" prettify.txt | tail -n 1 |awk '{print $1}'

grep "Label2" prettify.txt | awk '{print $3}'

grep -B 4 "Label3" prettify.txt | awk '{print $1}' RS=[ FS=] | tail -n 1

Extract 1

```
   <b>
    <font color="Red">
     Label1
    </font>
    <font color="blue">
     Value1
    </font>
   </b>
   <br />
   Label2: Value2
   <br />
```

Extract 2

```
    <li>
     <font color="green">
      [value3]
     </font>
     <font color="red">
      Label3
     </font>
    </li>
```

Comment: What's the question?  What code have you tried?  What doesn't work?

Comment: Question: How do I extract Value1, Value2 and Value3 from the prettify output and store them as variables.

Comment: Hint: **Update** the question is the expectation.  The comment isn't helpful, since it merely repeats the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some hackish coding before where I've curled a page then used the find function inside a tuple in order to strip out data from the rest of the content. 
Such as:

```
resultant_value = result[result.find(beginning_location):result.find(ending_location)]
```

the variables `beginning_location` and `ending_location` could be certain unique indicators at the beginning and ending of the value so that it is stripped out and placed into the variable `resultant_value`. Hope my hackish method helps in some way or another!

Comment: Thanks will see if I can get it to work. First go at programming so reading lots achieving little.

Comment: Best of luck! if you need help just shoot me an email sbrichards [at] mit.edu and ill try and help :)